# Gem update fails, no Xcode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubygems

I ran sudo gem update earlier today and was thrilled to see it work, but at the end it failed.

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

ruby extconf.rb update
can't find header files for ruby.
```

I don't have Xcode, and if possible, I don't want to install it. Any other way to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to install xcode to get the c libraries that are required to build the c native extensions for some ruby gems.  Is there any reason you dont want to install Xcode?

Comment: I don't have that much space on my old G4.

Comment: Maybe it's time to upgrade your harddisk, since you are going to need Xcode in order to compile native gems.

Comment: here is the error:
sudo gem install rails
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

ruby extconf.rb install rails
can't find header files for ruby.


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/fcgi-0.8.7 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/fcgi-0.8.7/ext/fcgi/gem_make.out

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583360/gcc-without-xcode-on-os-x) and [this thread on the MacRumors forums](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=596565). It looks like it's possible to install gcc & the right libraries without all of Xcode now, but you'll still need to download the whole DMG from Apple.

Answer (score 0):

I appears to be looking for (part of) the source for Ruby. You might try getting that and installing it too.