# Poorly Formatted Hard Drive: cannot install XCode/C++?

Tags: xcode, format, hard-drive

### Background

Using a refurbished Macbook.  I need to update my current version of C++ - currently using `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1`.  I understand the easiest way to update is to simply download the latest version of XCode (currently not downloaded).

When I try and install from the App Store, I get:
[image]
My drive is formatted as shown below:

```
 MacBook-Pro: pwd
/

 MacBook-Pro: ls
Applications              Users                     dev                       net                       tmp
Library                   Volumes                   etc                       opt                       usr
Network                   bin                       home                      private                   var
System                    cores                     installer.failurerequests sbin

 MacBook-Pro: cd Volumes

 MacBook-Pro: ls
Data OS

 MacBook-Pro: cd Data

 MacBook-Pro: ls
Applications           Library                Pictures               downloads              repos
Desktop                Movies                 calibrationResearch    iCloud Drive (Archive) screenshots
Google Drive           Music                  documents              miniconda2
```

### Question

- Is there a way I can move my system and home folders (`Data` and `OS`?) to the same directory?
- If not, is there another easy way to get C++ 11?

Comment: what if you just click ok will it not install?

Comment: `We could not complete your purchase` - apparently there is not enough space, despite having more than 100GB available under `Storage`!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install gcc on mac osx without installing xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307433/install-gcc-on-mac-osx-without-installing-xcode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try downloading from here instead of going through the store

https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

if that doesn't work install the xcode command line tools from the same link and install gcc from homebrew like the following article shows

http://www-scf.usc.edu/~csci104/20142/installation/gccmac.html

Comment: That's awesome, thanks for the link Steve! You're a beauty!