# g++ in mac osx 10.7

Tags: c++, macos

Could it be possible that the g++ compiler was removed in mac os x 10.7?
I didn't find anything when I search after it, but I was sure that I had it installed before 10.7.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I have Xcode Version 3.2.4 installed

Comment: Hmm..strange it worked before the os update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the update removes some installed components, among them Java and the OS X managed GCC installation. If you had Xcode installed before, it won’t be usable any longer.

[You need to (re)install the **current Xcode** version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/583360/1968) from the App Store to use GCC.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed Xcode?
If not, you won't have it...

You may also have a problem with your $PATH environment variable.

g++ is located in /usr/bin/, on OS X 10.7.

Try this:

```
ls -al /usr/bin/g++
```

If you got it, then check your $PATH environment variable.

```
echo $PATH
```

Comment: Was also relevant for OS X 10.15.7

Answer (score 0):

It comes with the developer tools, so it should be on your system if you have xcode installed. On my machine with xcode 4.1 there is g++ installed.

Xcode 4.1 is available freely in the app store.