# g++: error: unable to find utility "g++", not a developer tool or in PATH

Tags: xcode, g++

I'm trying to compile my code with g++

```
g++ practice.cpp
```

I have xcode command line tools installed, but I get this error. What should I do?

```
sh: line 1:  1258 Abort trap: 6           /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk macosx -find g++ 2> /dev/null
g++: error: unable to find utility "g++", not a developer tool or in PATH
```

Comment: Didn't you try the *gcc* command? That's what we use for g++

Comment: I tried gcc and had the same error

Comment: Could you include your command used as part of the question? That'll make it easier to recognise the problem.

Comment: I presume you're using Linux or MacOS

Comment: I'm using MacOS

Comment: I'm not sure about setting the path on a Mac, but here's something I think may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445355/g-in-mac-osx-10-7

Comment: Have you set the `SDKROOT` environment variable? If so, what is its value?