# Extraction of text from Image in Jmeter

Tags: javascript, java, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a requirement to extract number(digits) from Image on the disk . Do we have any library/plugin for jmeter which can do this ?
For example I have the Image [image]

on the disk I want to extract the digits from this image .
My output should be : 5693478605

Comment: [take a look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813881/java-ocr-implementation)

Comment: @Rick Can you please elaborate it , how i can include it with the Jmeter?

Answer (score 0):

Extracting text from image is known as "Optical character recognition" (optical character reader, OCR).

Below links may help you.

[Turn Image into Text - Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10419577/turn-image-into-text-java)

[Do any Java OCR tools convert images of text into editable text files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12731817/do-any-java-ocr-tools-convert-images-of-text-into-editable-text-files)

[API to read text from Image file using OCR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22531656/api-to-read-text-from-image-file-using-ocr)