# ruby-1.9.2 won't install - could not find compiler and 'make' tool

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

Every time I run `rvm install ruby-1.9.2-p320` I get the following message.

```
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.8/x86_64/ruby-1.9.2-p320.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Can not find compiler and 'make' tool - make sure Xcode and/or Command Line Tools are installed.
Requirements installation failed with status: 11.
```

I am just starting to try to learn to program and I understand I need to be able to install and run different versions of ruby other than the default 1.8.something. I have close to no idea what I am doing so please dumb-down any answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This line says it all: **Can not find compiler and 'make' tool - make sure Xcode and/or Command Line Tools are installed.**

Comment: It's recommended (e.g., here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360110/installing-gcc-to-mac-os-x-leopard-without-installing-xcode) to install Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

As very obvious by the error that rvm is looking for gcc compiler is not able to find it.
Two ways to fix this:
1) 
  Install the gcc compiler specific to your osx form 
https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer

2)

1. Install Xcode
2. Since the latest version of xcode no longer ship command line tools with it, install command-line tools

[Xcode 4.4 and later install Command Line Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-4-4-command-line-tools)

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_3.html