# C++ Development on Mac OSX 10.6

Tags: c++, macos

I am away for 2 weeks with my Macbook Pro 13" running OSX 10.6. I want to continue my learning and development of C++ applications. I don't have my applications CD which apparently comes with XCode, so I was hoping someone could help me get up and running developing C++ applications using either Netbeans or Eclipse.

On the Netbeans website, it said I needed to install XCode (not feasible since its a 3.5gb download), and I couldn't find a C++ compiler download for Eclipse, or instructions on how to install it after I DO find one.

Can someone help? Thanks

Comment: why not just use vim and g++ on the command line?  you'll learn a lot more that way than using a pretty ide i guarantee you :P

Comment: I vaguely remember entering g++ into the terminal and getting nothing. I don't have a C++ compiler installed on my computer yet -- thats the problem.

Comment: @calavera - you need to install the XCode tools to get GCC on a Mac. @shadowprotocol - can you use clang? I forget if OSX 10.6 comes with clang c++ by default.

Comment: @shadowprotocol: definitely follow Charlie Martin's advice and install MacPorts.  I believe it will install all the gcc compiler stuff without you having to do anything else.  If you then want to play around with programming in the latest version of vim, do `sudo port install vim`.

Comment: @birryee: i forgot it's not on there by default... i installed xcode and macports so long ago :)  vim is there, however it's 7.2 I think. MacPorts has the latest.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114884/is-there-a-way-to-install-gcc-in-osx-without-installing-xcode

Comment: You can download XCode for free at http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/mac/index.action

Comment: MacPorts also requires XCode to compile anything.

Comment: @Matt: But he said he didn't want a 3 GB download.

Comment: Uh, yes, that's why MacPorts is not an option either.

Comment: Come to think of it, aren't all the development tools on the OS/X DVD now a days?  WHy not just install from there?

Comment: @Charlie: he said he doesn't have the CD.

Answer (score 2):

Go to a local retailer that sells Apple products and buy a Snow Leopard DVD.  It will have the developer tools on it, albeit not the newest version. $30 US seems like a reasonable trade for two weeks of productivity.

Comment: or better yet to to a place with high speed internet and download it for free.  Like the Apple store :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the Eclipse C/C++ Development tools:

http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/

Comment: needs XCode: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&goto=553479&S=eb7ca84d740552e7e38e44d3ecc4ebab

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that.  Sorry, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You can pick up [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/), which will install the gcc tools in command-line versions.  There's undoubtedly a way to get Eclipse to use it,

Comment: Doesn't macports require xcode dev tools?

Comment: @ergosys - I think it does. It needs GCC to build the GCC in MacPorts.

Answer (score 0):

LLVM has [Mac binaries](http://llvm.org/releases/download.html). You could then use LLVM and Clang to build GCC from source if you prefer. But ouch.

Answer (score 0):

If you have internet access while you're away, and don't want to install anything, just use an online compiler. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3916000/212858) for suggestions.