# Can I install/use git on OS X Yosemite without CLDT?

Tags: xcode, git, osx-yosemite

A friend of mine need to clone a git repo, but on his machine is xcode not installed and when he tries to use git his Macbook says

> The command git requires the command line developer tools, do you want to install them?

The picture is in German.

[image: git]

So is it possible to use git on OS X without Xcode?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114884/is-there-a-way-to-install-gcc-in-osx-without-installing-xcode

Comment: Does it work with the git installer aswell?

Comment: I have not tried but pretty confident that it should.

Comment: Hm... then his machine might be broken, he said, he has github for mac installed and git, but it shows this message anyway :(

Comment: He actually did execute /Applications/GitHub.app/Contents/Resources/git/bin/git binary not /usr/bin/git?

Comment: He just used `git clone <url>`

Comment: make sense. I guess he didn't set PATH env, so that git was /usr/bin/git. He should use /Applications/GitHub.app/Contents/Resources/git/bin/git instead of git, or set PATH env.

Comment: @KazukiSakamoto would you add that to your answer please? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using SourceTree.app?

http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/

SourceTree.app has also git binary.

```
$ SourceTree.app/Contents/Resources/git_local/bin/git --version
git version 2.2.1
```

**EDIT**

> he has github for mac installed and git, but it shows this message anyway :(

I guess he didn't set PATH env, so that git was /usr/bin/git. He should use /Applications/GitHub.app/Contents/Resources/git/bin/git instead of git, or set PATH env.

Comment: I accepted, your answer, because Sourcetree worked and we gonna try the `PATH` thing :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Instead of using the built-in `git` command:

- Install [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) if you haven't already:

  ```
  ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
  ```
- Run `brew update && brew install git`
- Restart Terminal (or close the current tab and open a new one)

---

Before you do this:

```
$ git --version
git version 1.9.3 (Apple Git-50)
```

After you do this:

```
$ git --version
git version 2.2.1
```

Comment: I'm not sure but I think Homebrew requires command line tools.

Comment: I was scared of that :(